# Amazon SES Sandbox is rejecting verified email address

Tags: amazon-ses

I have Amazon SES working and I can send emails to verified addresses.  I added a new address, verified it and I can not send email to that address.  What else I need to do to send email to that verified address ?  I understand email addresses are case sensitive. So that's not the issue

554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-2: xyz@gmail.com

Comment: When you successfully sent emails to verified addresses, did you do it on the AWS console or through the SDK from your app code? In my case, I was able to send through the console, but failed through the SDK. It turned out, I made a mistake in passing my AWS credentials.